# DrRacket: Server Client Based Game in 2htdp/universe

Tags: performance, client, server, racket

I have a game right now based on a server client communication. My problem is that with my codes right now, when a player sends a message to the server and the server updates the universe/world, it creates a bundle and sends that whole universe/world to the players. Due to the massive amount of data that the server must update, make a bundle, then send it to the players it creates a lag or slows down the game if more that a couple players decides to join in. From reading things online, I know that the player and the server must have almost the same copy of the universe and that what the server needs to only send out to the other players is what is being changed in the world and the players own world/universe would update the game. I also know that what must be changed are my protocols. This is what I have so far for my protocols for both server and client.

Player:

```
; Marshalling and unmarshalling

; shot --> message
(define (marsh-shot s)
  (list 'new-shot (posn-x s) (posn-y s)))

; string --> message
(define (marsh-rocket-move direction)
  (list 'rocket-move direction))

; message --> world
(define (unmarsh-world mess)
  (make-world (map (lambda (xn) (make-ar (first xn) (first (rest xn)))) 
                   (second mess))
              (map (lambda (xy) (make-posn (first xy) (first (rest xy)))) 
                   (third mess))
              (fourth mess)
              (map (lambda (xy) (make-posn (first xy) (first (rest xy)))) 
                   (fifth mess))
              (sixth mess)))


; message --> ar
(define (unmarsh-rckt-mv m)
  (make-ar (first (rest m))
           (first (rest (rest m)))))


; message --> shot
(define (unmarsh-shot m)
  (make-posn (first (rest m))
             (first (rest (rest m)))))

; mess --> string
(define (unmarsh-rm-ally mess)
  (second mess))


; mess --> ar
(define (unmarsh-new-ally mess)
   (make-ar (second mess)
            (third mess)))

; mess --> loa
(define (unmarsh-loa mess)
  (map (lambda (xy) (make-posn (first xy) (second xy)))
       (rest mess)))

; key processing

; loar --> number
(define (get-my-x l)
  (cond [(empty? l) (error "Could not find my x in the loar")]
        [(string=? (ar-name (first l)) MY-ID) (ar-x (first l))]
        [else (get-my-x (rest l))]))

; process-key: world key --> package or world
; Purpose: This function is the handler to process key events.
(define (process-key a-world key)
  ; prior or up
  (cond [(key=? "up" key) 
         (make-package 
          a-world
          (marsh-shot (make-posn (get-my-x (world-allies a-world)) ROCKET-Y)))]
        [(or (key=? "right" key) (key=? "left" key))
         (make-package
          a-world
          (marsh-rocket-move key))]
        [else a-world]))



; process-message: world message --> world
(define (process-message w mess)
  (cond [(symbol=? 'world (first mess)) 
         (unmarsh-world mess)]
        [else (error "World received an unknown message" mess)]))

; world --> boolean
(define (game-over? w) (world-over w))


(big-bang INIT-WORLD
          (on-draw draw-world)
          (on-key process-key)
          (on-receive process-message)
          (register LOCALHOST)
          (name MY-ID)
          (stop-when game-over?))
```

Server:

```
; Marshalling

; world string --> message
(define (marsh-world w)
  (list 
   'world
   (map (lambda (a)  (list (ar-x a) (ar-name a))) (world-allies w))
   (map (lambda (a) (list (posn-x a) (posn-y a))) (world-aliens w))
   (world-dir w)
   (map (lambda (s) (list (posn-x s) (posn-y s))) (world-shots w))
   (world-over w)))

; message --> string
(define (unmarsh-rocket-move m) (second m))

; message --> shot
(define (unmarsh-shot m)
  (make-posn (second m)
             (third m)))

; ar --> message
(define (marsh-rckt-mv an-ar)
  (list 'rocket-move (ar-x an-ar) (ar-name an-ar)))

; loa --> message
(define (marsh-loa a-loa)
  (cons 'init-army 
        (map (lambda (a)  (list (posn-x a)  (posn-y a))) 
             a-loa)))


; Universe handlers


; add-new-world: univ iworld --> bundle
(define (add-new-world u w)
  (cond [(empty? (univ-worlds u))
         (local [(define new-worlds (list w))
                 (define new-state  (make-world (list (make-ar (/ WIDTH 2) (iworld-name w)))
                                                INIT-LOA
                                                "left"
                                                INIT-LOS
                                                false))]
           (make-bundle 
            (make-univ new-worlds new-state)
            (list (make-mail w (marsh-world new-state)))
            empty))]
        [else
         (local [(define new-worlds (cons w (univ-worlds u)))
                 (define new-state (make-world (cons (make-ar (/ WIDTH 2) (iworld-name w))
                                                     (world-allies (univ-state u)))
                                               (world-aliens (univ-state u))
                                               (world-dir (univ-state u))
                                               (world-shots (univ-state u))
                                               false))]
           (make-bundle 
            (make-univ new-worlds new-state)
            (map (lambda (iw) (make-mail iw (marsh-world new-state))) new-worlds)
            empty))]))

; rm-world: symbol (listof iworld) --> univ
(define (rm-world name u)
  (cond [(empty? u) (error "World to remove for mail list not found")]
        [(string=? name (iworld-name (first u))) (rest u)]
        [else (cons (first u) (rm-world name (rest u)))]))

; rm-ally: name (listof ar) --> (listof ar)
(define (rm-ally nm l)
  (cond [(empty? l) (error "Ally to remove not found!")]
        [(string=? nm (ar-name (first l))) (rest l)]
        [else (cons (first l) (rm-ally nm (rest l)))]))

; rm-this-world: univ iworld --> bundle
(define (rm-this-world u iw)
  (local [(define new-worlds (rm-world (iworld-name iw) (univ-worlds u)))
          (define new-state  (make-world (rm-ally  (iworld-name iw) 
                                                   (world-allies (univ-state u)))
                                         (world-aliens (univ-state u))
                                         (world-dir (univ-state u))
                                         (world-shots (univ-state u))
                                         (world-over (univ-state u))))]
    (make-bundle (make-univ new-worlds new-state)
                 (map (lambda (iw) (make-mail iw (marsh-world new-state))) new-worlds)
                 empty)))

; shot los --> los
(define (update-shots s l) (cons s l))

; receive-message: univ iworld --> bundle
(define (receive-message u w msg)
  (cond [(symbol=? (first msg) 'rocket-move)
         (local [(define new-state (make-world (move-ally (world-allies (univ-state u))
                                                          (iworld-name w)
                                                          (unmarsh-rocket-move msg))
                                               (world-aliens (univ-state u))
                                               (world-dir (univ-state u))
                                               (world-shots (univ-state u))
                                               (world-over (univ-state u))))]
           (make-bundle (make-univ (univ-worlds u) new-state)
                        (map (lambda (iw) (make-mail iw (marsh-world new-state))) 
                             (univ-worlds u))
                        empty))]
        [(symbol=? (first msg) 'new-shot)
         (local [(define new-state (make-world (world-allies (univ-state u))
                                               (world-aliens (univ-state u))
                                               (world-dir (univ-state u))
                                               (update-shots (unmarsh-shot msg) 
                                                             (world-shots (univ-state u)))
                                               (world-over (univ-state u))))]
           (make-bundle (make-univ (univ-worlds u) new-state)
                        (map (lambda (iw) (make-mail iw (marsh-world new-state))) 
                             (univ-worlds u))
                        empty))]
        [else (error "Unknown message type sent to the server")]))

; world --> world
(define (game-over-world w)
  (make-world (world-allies w)
              (world-aliens w)
              (world-dir w)
              (world-shots w)
              true))

; univ --> univ
(define (update-univ u)
  (cond [(game-over? (univ-state u))
         (make-bundle u 
                      (map (lambda (iw) 
                             (make-mail iw (marsh-world (game-over-world (univ-state u)))))
                           (univ-worlds u))
                      empty)]
        [else 
         (local [(define new-world (update-world (univ-state u)))]
           (make-bundle
            (make-univ (univ-worlds u) new-world)
            (map (lambda (iw) (make-mail iw (marsh-world new-world))) (univ-worlds u))
            empty))]))



(universe initU
          (on-new add-new-world)
          (on-msg receive-message)
          (on-disconnect rm-this-world)
          (on-tick update-univ)
          )
```

Comment: Can you give an concrete example of how a message looks like? (At first glance your approach looks fine)